# Configure Windows for an internet connection that's only metered during the day

Tags: windows

Can the Windows 8/10 metered connection setting be scheduled to automatically turn on and off depending on the time of day in order to take advantage of an overnight unlimited traffic window from an otherwise metered ISP?  Having to turn it on and off manually is tedious and error prone; is there any way to automate doing so?

Comment: [How to set Metered Connection in Windows 10](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/set-metered-connection-in-windows-10): see 2nd half of article. Same approach should work for earlier versions of Windows.

Comment: @DavidPostill You misunderstand my question.  I'm not asking for where the user flip-able switch is.  I'm looking for a way to have the connection automatically switch to metered in the morning, and back to unmetered overnight because having to manually flip the switch twice a day is tedious an error prone (and in the case of metered with high overage fees can be an expensive error as well).

Comment: I didn't misunderstand your question. The link I gave you tells you how to do it from the command line. Stick those commands in 2 batch files (1 to turn it on, and the other to turn it off). Now run the batch files using the Task Scheduler ... with the trigger being the appropriate time of day ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open the Command Prompt.
2. Type in `netsh wlan show profiles`
3. Pick the profile you want to set to metered and copy it to your clipboard.
4. Now create a batch file with the following text in it (replace "Profile" with the profile you want to set to metered to),

   `@echo 
   netsh wlan set profileparameter name="Profile" cost=Fixed`
5. Create another batch file with the following text in it (replace "Profile" with the profile you want to set to metered to) this batch file will set it to unrestricted:

   `@echo off
   netsh wlan set profileparameter name="Profile" cost=Unrestricted`
6. Open `taskschd.msc` from "Run" using <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> or through the Start Menu.
7. Click on Task Scheduler Library.
8. In the Action pane on the right hand side click "Create Basic Task".
9. Go through the wizard for both batch files.

---

NOTE:

YOU MAY NEED TO EDIT THE TASKS YOU JUST CREATED AND ENABLE RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR!